# Elegant way to validate keyset of a map with an enum?

Tags: java, enums, guava, apache-commons

I have a map in which I need to validate keyset of map with my enum. I have an enum class as shown below:

```
  public enum Tag {
    rename, duplicate, process, limit, encode, decode;
  };
```

Now `keyset` of map should have values from above enum. If my keyset contains value which is not there in the enum, then I want to throw `IllegalArgumentException` with the value missing from my enum.

Below is my code:

```
  public Processor(Map<String, String> tasks) {
    Set<String> keyset = tasks.keySet();
    for (String tag : keyset)
      checkArgument(!EnumUtils.isValidEnum(Tag.class, tag), "unknown tag found '%s'.", tag);
  }
```

As you can see I am iterating `keyset` and doing `Preconditions.checkArgument` check. If it is not there then it will throw `IllegalArgumentException`. I am sure throwing message can be improved though.

My question is: Is there any better way to do the same thing as compared to what I am doing? Do I have to iterate the `keyset` in the for loop to do the check? or Is there any one liner or any other better way to do this validation?

I am using Java7.

Comment: If you want your map to have keys from the `Tag` enum, it really shouldn't be a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: Just use a `Map<Tag, String>`? Maybe even an `EnumMap`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing a bit too much work.  Realistically speaking, all you need to do is bind your key in your map to `Tag`.

```
public Processor(Map<Tag, String> tasks) {
    // processor logic    
}
```

This *guarantees* that the keys in the map passed in can *only* ever be `Tag`.  You also don't require the exception in this scheme, since your code will fail to compile if an invalid key is passed.  Also, since it's an enum, you're not going to get any keys that aren't in that enum.

If you're processing a list of strings and you can't get the enum directly, then you can use `Tag.valueOf("<string value here>")` to convert it.

Comment: The user wants to throw IllegalArgumentException...where is that thrown in your code ?????

Comment: @prashant You don't need to throw it.  This gives a compile time check to the map rather than a runtime check.  We've hashed over this already in your answer and I don't see any reason to rehash it here.

Comment: But the user wants to throw @Makoto....it could be for a business case where he wants to track such events.....

Comment: There is a need......for the user which I have addressed.....its not something which I have just come up with.........it was mentioned by the user......there is no logic in your downvoting my answer

Comment: My main intention first was to do what Makoto and Andy suggested but somehow I was not able to do that before so I decided to go to this route but now I am trying to see whether I can do the way Makoto and Andy are trying to say.

Comment: @Makoto Even though I was addressing a user requirement......simple question..tell me is not throwing IllegalArgumentException mentioned in his question ??...if so then please tell me which answer has addressed this

Comment: @prashant:  The OP is also asking for a better way to accomplish this, so I provided one.  Whether or not they can use it is one thing (although I do suspect they can - even with converting the strings to `Tag` enum values), but I feel quite satisfied in having supplied a suitable answer to the question.

Comment: @prashant:  In addition to this, I'd ask that you kindly calm down.  We've hashed and rehashed this and I really don't have the luxury of time to rehash it once more with you.